# Registering named service based on property

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

So what I want to do is something like ...

```
[Name("MY_CLASS")]
public class MyClass : IMyInterace {...}
```

or maybe

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterace {
    string Name => "MY_CLASS"; // part of interface
}
```

and then something in autofac something like ...

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(asm)
  .Where(...) // lazy typing that properly
  .Named<IMyInterface>(x => x.Name);
```

Is anything like that possible at all?

PS: I realize that I could just register these implementations as named services but that has two disadvantages:

1. lots of entries, and one more thing to forget when you add new stuff
2. the name and the class are in different places instead of nicely in one place

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve... why do you need to register your components with these dynamic keys? However you could check out the metadata support: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html

Comment: @nemesv: basically we get these magic keys from an API which then switches the behaviour. Currently it's like `switch (key) case "MY_CLASS" [code]`. So obviously it would be great to replace that with an `IIndex<string, IMyInterface>` and get rid of roughly 50 conditions ...

Comment: short answer is yes! i would recommend against the first 1.. as the class inheriting should be the factor which makes them unquic

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should think about this the other way, write code to find the classes you have available (reflection?), and when your condition is met, run a builder.RegisterType

Comment: I could also just plainly register them, inject an IEnumerable<IMyInterface>, and then go through them. That's not even extra effort performance-wise as everything is SingleInstance (a pain point in it's own, but I'm not changing that now).